# implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

Tags: c++

```
class Segment;
class Reactor;
class Client;
class Handler;

class SegmentInfo   
 64     {
 65     ▏   public:
 66     ▏   ▏   Segment segment;
 67     ▏   ▏   Reactor reactor;
 68     ▏   ▏   Client* client;
 69     ▏   ▏   queue<Handler*> pool;
 70 
 71     ▏   ▏   SegmentInfo(Segment _segment, int poolSize, Client* _client):
 72     ▏   ▏   ▏   segment(_segment), pool(poolSize), client(_client)
 73     ▏   ▏   {
 74 
 75     ▏   ▏   }
 76    };
```

```
error: use of deleted function ‘SegmentInfo::SegmentInfo(const SegmentInfo&)’

note: SegmentInfo::SegmentInfo(const SegmentInfo&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

So here is my code and I searched all over internet but not able to find resource/link/etc. on why this error is coming. So if you people can tell the root cause of this error and how to solve it, it will be very helpful!! Thank you!!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: g++ compiler it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196102/note-personperson-is-implicitly-deleted-because-the-default-definition-wo

Comment: actually i read this ans but doesn't get any intuition as I am not using any `const` or `constexpr`

Comment: do Segment and Reactor have a copy constructor?

Comment: They have not any copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that `SegmentInfo` has a member or inherits from someone with a deleted copy constructor. Note how this example gives you the same error:

```cpp
struct A
{
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(){}
};

struct B
{ 
    A a;
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    B b2 = b;
}
```